# How can i find a line in which the word variable matched

Tags: go

I need a line from a sentence in which the value of variable word match. For example, if the value of var word is **continue** then the result is
[I have to continue the task. Once enable then we will continue.]

The result is same if the value of variable word is **cont**
but I need the same result if the value of variable word is **continued**.
[i am trying following code](https://go.dev/play/p/ORXqEzr3jd9)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    word := "enabled"
    sentence := "Their have a problem with the server.I have to continue the task.Hope the server will enable for everyone.Once enable then we will continue."
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`[^.]*(?i)` + word + `[^.]*[\.| ]`)
    fmt.Println(re.FindAllString(sentence, -1))
    return
}
```

As per the following code I need the line from the variable **sentence** in which the var **word** matched, for example if the value of var word is **enable** the then result is

**[Hope the server will enable for everyone. Once enable, then we will continue.]**

The result is same for the value of var word is **enab**

I need the same result if the value of var word is **enabled**.

Answer (score 0):

I think with a little trial and error you could have found the answer :)
You weren't this far.

I've come up with `[A-Z][^.]*<your_word>[^.]*\.`, although I'm no regex expert, so there might be a better one.

You might want to try it here : https://regex101.com/r/l14O9I/1